# Does MAX3665 amplifier have a minimum operating frequency?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, high-speed

I am using the MAX3665 in a design. The amplifier has an IR Photodiode at the input and is failing to detect any signals. My signal generator outputs a maximum of MHz square waves and MHz sine waves.

How do I know what the operating frequency of the MAX3665 is?

Comment: It has a DC cancellation loop.

Comment: No link nor mention of the datasheet?

Answer (score 1):

The small signal response starts to drop significantly after 100kHz, flat from 500kHz to 700MHz. You should be able to see signals of a 100MHz. It could be something else. I would test the transmitter with a detector that you know that works to make sure that it's not the transmitter.

[image]